# Concrete5 Login to SSL Checkout page doesn't carry

Tags: php, ssl, e-commerce, concrete5

I'm working on a Concrete5 website that has [Lerteco Membership Commerce](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/lerteco-membership-commerce/) installed. I have [Force SSL](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/force-ssl/) also installed which makes the checkout pages secure but I do not have https on any of the other pages of the website. I have the login controller redirecting the user to a page that lists subscriptions.

So the user logs in, is redirected to a page describing subscriptions available, clicks into one of the subscriptions and then there is a checkout page with https in the URL. The checkout page detects that the user is logged in and auto-populates the username and email field with that of the registered user. The problem I am having is that every 15 times you login or so, the username and email fields are not populated as they should be, which confuses the user. I have done quite a bit of logging and it seems that the user is indeed logged in but when they hit one of the checkout pages, they are no longer logged in. It seems to happen more often when the user has not logged in for at least an hour (though this could be in my head as I can't seem to replicate it turning browser cache off and deleting site cookies). **If only I could get a hint as to what is going on? Any ideas?**

1)Step One Log In (note no SSL)
[image: Logging In to Peaceful Schools]

2)Redirect to available memberships page (note no SSL)
[image: Subscriptions Page]

3a)Checkout page is pre-populated with username and email (90% of the time)
[image: Checkout]

3b)This error happens sometimes instead where the username and email fields are NOT pre-populated (see also how there is no username greeting in heading like last image).
[image: Error]

Comment: Just a theory, when they log in and it doesn't get sent forward, are they somehow using www. and then being redirected to the subscription page without the www.? Not sure how that gets sent forward but if it is via cookie that could be the cause.

Comment: I think maybe it was actually. Once I put force ssl on all of the pages through checkout, I no longer was having this issue.